# Proof about derivatives that involve constants

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, derivatives, continuity

I was asked to solve the following problem that involves derivatives and constants and I believe that I got the idea of how to prove it, but I would appreciate a second look from someone with more expertise at my proof.

> The problem:

Given that $f$, and $g$ are differentiable at $x_0$. If $\alpha ∈ R$. Show that $(\alpha f)'(x_0)$ = $\alpha f'(x_0)$.

> My attempt:

$\begin{align*}(\alpha f)'(x_0)=lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}
&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\alpha f(x_0)-\alpha f(a)}{x_0-a}\\ 
&=\alpha\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x_0)- f(a)}{x_0-a} ~~~~(by~~the~~properties~~of~~a~~limit.) \\
&=\alpha f'(x_0)\\
\end{align*}$ 

 

Would this be sufficient to prove the question?

Thanks a whole lot!

Comment: Yes! Looks good. Not much more to say. Also if $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ it means that $$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0 -x}$$ exists. So I’m not sure what $a$ is in your proof.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Would I need to add a double implication sign (⇔), however, to show that this can be done both ways since it's required to show that they are equal?

Comment: I see! I just used the general definition of a derivative in this case and it didn't really come to mind that it should be written like so. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Np! Furthermore you are proving an equality, so the “if and only if” is already provided by the symmetric property.